# How to handle special UTF8 Characters in body_html while updating a product?

Tags: javascript, shopify, non-ascii-characters

I am updating products using the API. However when there is a non-ASCII (greater than 0x7f) in the body_html field, the product does not get updated.

for example:

```
 body_html: "<b>Acer’s Aspire®</b>"
```

fails without any errors/warning

Comment: Is that a `&reg;​​​​​​​​​` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/V5YxT/) ?

Comment: I am getting the product content from another source. And I get returned a UTF8 string like this `Acer’s Aspire®`. I think the `®` is not causing the problem, it's the `’` that is causing the problem

Comment: Ok, by replacing both these characters, the request goes through just fine.

Comment: Are you trying to update into a database or what ?

Comment: I am using the Shopify.com's API. I am making an HTTPS request to their servers, using Node.js

Comment: Opps! I missed it, `node.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the issue with this: http://mothereff.in/js-escapes

However, I think Shopify should resolve this issue on the backend.